# Getting Error TF400071: The provisioned service account for this collection could not be retrived while setting TFS

Tags: azure-devops

Please suggest me how to overcome, I am getting Error TF400071: The provisioned service account for this collection could not be retrieved. when I enter account name , https://example.visualstudio.com/   here account name I am using is the name that i have on the place of example while setting TFS to run my selenium test.

The error is 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use service account **Account Service** to communicate with the hosted service. This service account is created automatically when you create a collection in VSTS.

Comment: I am new to this and not sure when & where I created a collection in VSTS. Could you please provide me the steps so that i can get this Account Service.

Comment: @Shekhar VSTS only has one team project collection, which is default. If you has a VSTS account, the account Account Service should has been there. Can you test pass if you type Account Service under Hosted Team Foundation Server Service Account?